# Quickest Way To Open Excel

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have been using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library to open Excel, refresh some queries and save.  The issue I am running into is this will only work if each computer has the same Excel library as selected in the project installed on the PC.

I see that NPOI can http://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation read and write data to Excel, but what about an even simpler task of open/refresh/save, can NPOI handle this?

If you use this syntax it seems I can open my Excel file, but what about refreshing queries and saving?

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\test.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      hssfwb= new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
```

Comment: I cannot speak to NPOI, but some Office version independence can be achieved by embedding COM interop types into your assembly.  For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OLEDB adapter also

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + excelfilepath+ "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";"); /*for office 2007 connection*/
conn.Open();
   string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + Table + "]";
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
 System.Data.DataTable ExcelToDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(ExcelToDataTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

By 'refresh queries' I assume you mean that the Excel file is linked to some data source, and you want to update the content of the Excel file with the current data from that data source.

If you want that to be "automatic" (i.e. you don't write the code to do this updating yourself), then I think Excel is the only way to go. I'm pretty sure that something like NPOI (or EPPlus, or ClosedXML) would not do that. However, you might be able to use those libraries to insert values into the spreadsheet yourself, if you can easily query the data source.

Since you're talking about multiple computers, I assume that you're building either an add-in or an EXE that gets deployed to various users. In that case, you probably want to build against the lowest-supported version of Excel that you can. In other words, you want (say) Excel 2003 or 2007 on your development machine. (You'll make your life much easier if you can drop support for 2003).

If you build against Excel 200x, then it should run fine on later versions. That's not the case the other way around. Note that you don't want to have more than one version on your development machine.

Comment: With the COM references, you can only have 1 reference installed at a time.  So I have been unable to find a way to build for 2003 and have it open 2007 or vice-versa.  Hence me looking into one of the other .dll's possible.

Comment: Yes, but COM components tend to be backward-compatible, so that if you've referenced version 1.x and the user has version 2.x, it'll still work.

Comment: Not in my experience.  For example, if I use the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library and instantiate Excel like so, if the user does not have Excel 2007 installed it will error out the syntax every time. public static Excel.Application oXL;

oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
oXL.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;

Comment: It should work. How are you deploying your EXE? You would need to ensure that the Primary Interop Assembly from the version of Excel you build with is copied to the deployment folder, rather than relying on a newer version of the PIA in the GAC.

Comment: I was using a windows form.  But did not ensure the PIA from my version of Excel was copied to the deployment folder.  How would I go about that?

Comment: Ah, deployment issues. I remember getting to 90% complete when I created my first add-in, only to find that there was another 90% still to do on "deployment". It's hard, and it's not fun (although it should be easier in your case because you're not creating an add-in, and so don't have to worry about the Office security model). I can't give you an answer in a comment, and I'd be doing so from distant memory anyway. Best do some googling, or ask another question. But in the short term, just copy the PIA dlls to your installation folder, even if you have to do it manually.